# Open CV - reducing video file size

Tags: opencv

I want to use OpenCV to take an input video, and reduce the file size of the video.

This would require a conversion of the frames from the initial type to some transformed type.

What conversion can I use inside OpenCV so that I take each frame of the video, reduce its size and then write back to create a new file with reduced file size without much compromising with the video quality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV uses FFMPEG. Check [this](http://ffmpeg.org/) link for a detailed instructions, You can use FFMPEG independently instead of OpenCV. If you already have compressed video data, you wont be able to do much compression unless you loose quality for reduce the frame size instead.

Comment: No I want to use Open CV to do this...how do I do it?

Comment: Well i assume you can open a movie in openCV. Depends if you are using C or C++ API. After that, you read each frame and process it.

Comment: Check these links to get hold of reading videos - http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/opencv-intro.html#SECTION00070000000000000000       and http://areshopencv.blogspot.com/2010/12/load-video-in-opencv.html

Comment: I can easily load a video and process each frame in a frame by frame fashion. I want to know what type of conversion will result in a reduced file size ? eg. LoG operator, Gaussian, etc

Comment: Nope nope, For that go through video compression such as H264, MJPEG and try understanding a bit about these first.